# What would cause an iframe to keep loading its parent page?

Tags: html, iframe, razor

So this is quite the odd situation.... I have an `iframe` on a `.cshtml` page that is continuously loading the full content of the page that the `iframe` is on.  This is the code for the iframe:

`<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/dir/file.html")" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="yes" />`

The directory for the file is correct and the `file.html` file displays correctly without error when it is opened by itself.  Also, I have tried using a different `test.html` file in place of `file.html` so the error cannot be within that file.  Removing the `iframe` tag obviously stops this issue from occurring.

The other really interesting part about this issue is that I have a working version of the application that this `.cshtml` file belongs to and I have compared the corresponding `.cshtml` files and they are identical so I am really bewildered by this.  Has anybody ever experienced a situation like this?  The `iframe` literally just keeps reloading the `.cshtml` file within the `iframe` until I tell the browser to stop loading so you end up with a page with an `iframe`, that has a page withing the `iframe`, that has a page within the `iframe`, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question lies within the authentication for the application.  When the `iframe` would make a call to `file.html` it would receive a redirect back to the `.cshtml` page which of course had the `iframe` on it so you can see where the loop comes into play.  The solution of course then is to change the security settings to allow it to call to `file.html` as it needs to be displayed there.  Thanks anyway.